# Using GET to register button click

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to register a button click on my website using PHP.The click downloads a file to client's machine. Database connection was tested before and it works fine. I just need to register that click into DB. Here is my code, could you guide me through?

```
echo '<div id="fdbox1"><h2>Details</h2><p><a href="open/?f='.$reqfile.'&amp;l=pdf&amp;r='.time().'&amp;dl=true"> Download full details in PDF format ('.$file_size.')</a></p></div>';
if(isset($_GET['dl']))
                {
                    $server = "xx.xxx.xx.xxx";
                    $dbusername = "xxxx";
                    $dbpassword = "xxxx";
                    $database = "xxxx";
                    $dbcon =  new mysqli($server,$dbusername,$dbpassword, $database);
                    $userid = $_SESSION['suserid'];
                    $date_downloaded = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

                    $sql = "INSERT INTO external_activity (
                            userid,
                            saleid,
                            activity,
                            date_register,

                                ) VALUES (
                            '".$userid."',
                            '".$ref_no."',
                            '".'Downloaded file'."',
                            '".$date_downloaded."'
                                )";
                    $dbcon->query($sql);
                    $dbcon->close();
                }
```

Comment: `date_register,` < that trailing comma, is an issue. Checking for errors would have told you about it. Then `'".'Downloaded file'."'` that should also throw you an error.

Comment: @Fred-ii-  Still getting no results inside DB table

Comment: edit your question accordingly then. Some future answers may post one because of that. You have answers below now.

Comment: What does `$dbcon->query($sql)` return? If it returns `false` the query could not be executed

Comment: @FilipJ.J. Your question remains unclear as to what you're now using for code. Check for errors via PHP and MySQL. Again; you've been given answers below but you've yet to let anyone know whether one of those worked or not. You're not helping anyone here by remaining silent.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Sorry to keep you waiting. I am trying to fight this problem. None of the proporsals work for me. I am trying play with ajax but it keeps failing. Are there any other solutions to do that kind of action?

Comment: @FilipJ.J. I don't mind waiting, just as long as I get pinged whenever I leave a question *haha!* and thanks for that. However, you shouldn't be telling "me" that none of those worked, but leaving a comment under each answer given. They too don't know if it worked for you or not, since you haven't commented under them. TBH, ajax/JS isn't my strong point. I'm mostly a serverside coder, so I won't be able to help you out there. Use error reporting, error checking on your query and look at your console. Wish I could help you out more, sorry.

Comment: @rbr94 query is working fine

Comment: @Fred-ii- Thats ok. Thanks for your time anyway. Thing is I am also not a good guy to deal with frontend stuff. Prefer backend but oh well. Need to cope with it and solve the problem. Thanks for your time once more.

Comment: @FilipJ.J. You're welcome. I placed an answer for you below that you can consult with and I've done my best to try and help you out. I hope you get some good information/help from it, *cheers*

Answer (score 0):

If using jquery is an option, you could create a "register_click.php", paste the `if(isset($_GET['dl']))` stuff inside and call it via ajax using an onclick listener that you will have to create and bind to the anchor.

Comment: I will try that as soon as I can and will let you know about it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it with POST data instead of GET.

```
$i = 0;
if $_POST['submit'] {
    $i++;
    $number_of_times_clicked = $number_of_times_clicked_stored_into_database + $i;
}
```

After that restore the new value back into the database. If you really want the onclick you need javascript. PHP is unable to check when a button is clicked, since the code only works once when the page is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

**This is too long for a comment.**

The `&amp;` in your code might give you some problems, I said *"might"*. If so, then consider changing those to `&` (ampersands).

Should it be the case, then you could change:

```
echo '<div id="fdbox1"><h2>Details</h2><p><a href="open/?f='.$reqfile.'&amp;l=pdf&amp;r='.time().'&amp;dl=true"> Download full details in PDF format ('.$file_size.')</a></p></div>';
```

to:

```
echo '<div id="fdbox1"><h2>Details</h2><p><a href="open/?f='.$reqfile.'&l=pdf&r='.time().'&dl=true"> Download full details in PDF format ('.$file_size.')</a></p></div>';
```

Then you will need to check and see if each GET array is is set/not empty with `isset()` and `!empty()`.

References:

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php

I only see `if(isset($_GET['dl']))` as a single array, so it's unsure as to how you're wanting to fetch the other GET arrays in your URL and if you did set those.

Your present code (if it's the full code), will throw a few notices about certain variables not being defined.

For example, the `if(isset($_GET['dl']))` and using the other GET arrays, would look like this:

```
if( isset($_GET['f']) && !empty($_GET['l'])  && !empty($_GET['dl'])  ){
    // do something inside here
}
```

You also need to make sure that the session was indeed started with `session_start();` and to be included inside all files using sessions.

Reference:

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php

This is usually the first line under the opening PHP tag.

```
<?php 

session_start();

// rest of your code
```

The `$userid = $_SESSION['suserid'];` needs to have a value/equal something, so that is unknown as to whether or not there is indeed a value for it.

Error reporting will be of help here for you, as will checking for errors against your query.

References:

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php

You also have a trailing comma in `date_register,` < and that needs to be removed, as I already stated in comments.

That alone would have thrown a syntax error.

The use of `'".'Downloaded file'."'` is unclear. If you just want to insert the `Downloaded file` as a string, then you can just place it inside single quotes `'Downloaded file'` and do:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO external_activity (
                            userid,
                            saleid,
                            activity,
                            date_register

                                ) VALUES (
                            '".$userid."',
                            '".$ref_no."',
                            'Downloaded file',
                            '".$date_downloaded."'
                                )";
```

Make sure that the `date_register` column type is DATE and not VARCHAR or other format. Although VARCHAR would not throw an error, it's best to use MySQL's built-in dating functions; that column's type is unknown.

Now, make sure that the `userid` column is not an AUTO_INCREMENT'ed column, otherwise your code will fail.

If the ultimate goal here is to "UPDATE" that userid column, then use just that, UPDATE:

- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/update.html

You also need to make sure that all columns' types are correct and have a length long enough to accomodate the incoming data and that there are no characters that MySQL will complain about, such as apostrophes.

Escaping those with a prepared statement will ensure that it doesn't throw/cause a syntax error and is something you should be using in order to help prevent against an SQL injection and you are open to one right now.

References:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection

This is the best way that I can offer for the question, given the information left in the question.

- Again; check for errors. That is one of the most important things that needs to be done during the development of your code.